# LFSR sequence computation

Tags: cryptography, pseudo-random-generators, shift-register

I need to calculate the output of the sequence generated by this shift register but I cannot find anywhere how to do it. Everywhere the results are just given but there is no explanation how to do compute them. I know the the sequence will repeat every 2^3-1=7 times. Could anyone explain me how to do it. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be simple:

First, we XOR the two least significant bits (LSB) to get the most significant bit. The two LSB are obtained by right-shifting. So, calculating in this way, we get the sequence 110, 111, 011, 001, 100, 010, 101.

Comment: The answer 110, 111, 011, 001, 100, 010, 101 is the sequence of _successive states_ or contents of the LFSR. The _sequence of outputs_ is 1011100... and repeats periodically with period 7.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, assuming that the outgoing bit from the shift register is taken as the output.